# ISPmanager: удалил пакеты через apt remove, затем их вернул, но в ISPmanager пропали вкладки. Как восстановить ISPmanager

Tags: linux, ispmanager

Удалил пакеты: `apt remove php7.0-*`, в том числе там были:

- `libapache2-mod-php7.0`
- `ispmanager-pkg-proftpd`
- `ispmanager-pkg-exim`, `ispmanager-pkg-opendkim-exim`

Как результат, сайт перестал работать. Поставил обратно все пакеты (взял с истории `/var/log/apt/history.log`), восстановил конфиги (предварительно добавил `/etc/` под `git`, поэтому `git checkout .`).

Сайт поднялся, но в `ISPmanager` пропали вкладки почта, домены, сайты, ftp, сертификаты.

Догадываюсь, что настройки еще где-то, кроме `/etc/` есть. Где они и как восстановить то, что было?

Comment: В `/var/lib`, `/opt`, `/var/cache`?

Comment: Опять же. Если у тебя есть пакеты с `ispmanager*`, то открой их через `mc` и пошарься по дереву папок внутри пакета. Особенно посмотри на `postinst`, `preinst`, `постремув` или как-то так, не помню.